# Trying to run ArcMap says appropriate license not given to program?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, license

I am trying to run ArcMap 10.4 on Windows 10 with a checked out license, and I get this error:

[image]

When I turn off my Wi-Fi and intiate ArcMap, it works, then I can turn the Wi-Fi back on and continue to do what I need to.

Have any of you encountered this?